# index.php into subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Is it possible to have my index.php into subdirectory but the rest website to be under the public_html folder?
i mean something like that:

```
public_html/here is the website files
public_html/directory/here is the index.php
```

So the homepage url its going to be:

```
www.example.com/directory
```

and the links will be going to default - EG: my about page will be:

```
www.example.com/about
```

Is it possible? How can i do that?

Comment: Yes possible.. you can

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Read this: https://perishablepress.com/redirect-subdirectory-to-root-via-htaccess/

Comment: Yes, but usually it's the opposite way round, or website files are outside the website root, and everything is routed through index.php